# Can Lunala fuse with Necrozma in regular Pokemon Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I was wondering if I can fuse my Necrozma and Lunala in Pokemon Moon (not Ultra version). Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

No, Dusk Mane and Dawn Wings Necrozma are UltraSun/UltraMoon exclusive.

[image]